# FFmpeg settings for encoding for 4K UHD Blu-ray Disc

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

What FFmpeg settings should I use for taking raw video and converting it to `x265` for 4K UHD Disc? This is a 1-Pass example.

Are there more `-x265-params` needed?

For Audio, will DTS `-c:a dca -strict -2` be compatible with 4K discs and palyers? Also what is the Lossless command for `dca`?

---

Here is what I've got so far:

```
ffmpeg -y 

-i rawvideo 

-c:v libx265 
-preset slow -b:v 50M -maxrate 75M -bufsize 75M 
-pix_fmt yuv420p10le 
-r 60 
-vf "scale=3840:-2" 
-profile:v main10 -level 5.1 -sar 1:1 -x265-params "colorprim=bt2020:transfer=bt2020:colormatrix=bt2020" 
-map 0:v:0?

-c:s mov_text 
-map 0:s? 

-c:a dca -strict -2 
-b:a 1509k 
-map 0:a? 

-f mp4 

-threads 0 

output.mp4
```

Comment: Does that code work or not?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend 1-pass target bitrate encodes. Rather do a two-pass to get better quality distribution. Are you running into any problems?

Comment: @music2myear That script will encode a video that works on PC, but I'm currently not able to test it on a disc and player. I'm working on an FFmpeg project with someone, they wanted to know the settings for this. If they can burn a disc I can ask them how it works.